# CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:7 (PROJECT): Failed to run MSBuild command:

Tags: cmake, lightgbm

I am building a GPU Version of lightgbm(Windows). I've followed all the Installation Guide in https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/blob/master/docs/Installation-Guide.rst#build-gpu-version:

> Windows On Windows GPU version of LightGBM can be built using OpenCL,
>   Boost, CMake and VS Build Tools or MinGW.
>
> If you use MinGW, the build procedure is similar to the build on
>   Linux. Refer to GPU Windows Compilation to get more details.
>
> Following procedure is for the MSVC (Microsoft Visual C++) build.
>
> Install Git for Windows, CMake (3.8 or higher) and VS Build Tools (VS
>   Build Tools is not needed if Visual Studio (2015 or newer) is
>   installed).
>
> Install OpenCL for Windows. The installation depends on the brand
>   (NVIDIA, AMD, Intel) of your GPU card.
>
> For running on Intel, get Intel SDK for OpenCL. For running on AMD,
>   get AMD APP SDK. For running on NVIDIA, get CUDA Toolkit. Further
>   reading and correspondence table: GPU SDK Correspondence and Device
>   Targeting Table.
>
> Install Boost Binary.
>
> Note: Match your Visual C++ version:
>
> Visual Studio 2015 -> msvc-14.0-64.exe,
>
> Visual Studio 2017 -> msvc-14.1-64.exe.
>
> Run the following commands:
>
> ```
> Set BOOST_ROOT=C:\local\boost_1_64_0\
> Set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR=C:\local\boost_1_64_0\lib64-msvc-14.0
> git clone --recursive https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM
> cd LightGBM
> mkdir build
> cd build
> cmake -DCMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM=x64 -DUSE_GPU=1 ..
> cmake --build . --target ALL_BUILD --config Release
> ```

But in the last step when I input

```
cmake -DCMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM=x64 -DUSE_GPU=1 ..
```

I got the error:

```
C:\Windows\System32\LightGBM\build>cmake -DCMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM=x64 -DUSE_GPU=1 ..
-- Selecting Windows SDK version  to target Windows 10.0.17134.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:7 (PROJECT):
  Failed to run MSBuild command:

    C:/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/14.0/bin/MSBuild.exe

  to get the value of VCTargetsPath:

    Microsoft (R) 生成引擎版本 14.0.25420.1
    版权所有(C) Microsoft Corporation。保留所有权利。

    MSBUILD : error MSB1009: 项目文件不存在。
    开关:VCTargetsPath.vcxproj


  Exit code: 1



-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Windows/System32/LightGBM/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

**CMakeOutput.log**:

```
The system is: Windows - 10.0.17134 - AMD64
```

Comment: C:\Windows\System32\LightGBM\build>cmake -DCMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM=x64 -DUSE_GPU=1 ..
-- Selecting Windows SDK version  to target Windows 10.0.17134.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:7 (PROJECT):
  Failed to run MSBuild command:

    C:/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/14.0/bin/MSBuild.exe

  to get the value of VCTargetsPath:

    Microsoft (R) 生成引擎版本 14.0.25420.1
    版权所有(C) Microsoft Corporation。保留所有权利。

    MSBUILD : error MSB1009: 项目文件不存在。
    开关:VCTargetsPath.vcxproj


  Exit code: 1



-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Windows/System32/Ligh.........

Comment: Please add additional information to your question using the `edit` button under the question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we expect all information related to the problem to be **in the question post itself**, not in the *comments*. Also we expect to have the error log as a **text**, not as an *image*. Please, fix these issues with your question post.